# Find discarded points in rdp (Ramer–Douglas–Peucker) algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm

Is there a way to find also the discarded points from rdp algorithm in python?

The algorithm:

```
from rdp import rdp

rdp([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]])
```

Gives the points remaining after compression:

```
[[1, 1], [4, 4]]
```

If I have a large dataset and apply the algorithm, I want to find the discarded points. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by the documentation, `rdp` can return a *mask* of the remaining points, it also provides an interface for numpy arrays.

One solution will be to combined the mask with numpy indexing for retrieving both the remaining and discarded points:

```
import numpy as np
from rdp import rdp

arr = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]])
mask = rdp(arr, return_mask=True)

print("remaining: {}".format(arr[mask]))
print("discarded: {}".format(arr[~mask]))
```

**Output**

```
remaining: [[1 1]
 [4 4]]
discarded: [[2 2]
 [3 3]]
```

**Note**

The `arr[mask]` notation means select those points where the mask is positive, and `arr[~mask]` select those points where the mask is negative.